# Can I get a warning when merging folders?

Tags: nemo

I used windows prior to Ubuntu. In windows when I merged folders it would give me a warning and ask my if I wanted to merge the folders, In ubuntu it just merges, the merging works fine but I would like to see some kind of dialogue verifying that I want to merge folders. Right now I only get get a warning when I overwrite a file. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and nemo as my file manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nemo is not the default file manager in Ubuntu. Nautilus is. And if you use Nautilus, you will receive a warning in this sense:

[image: File conflict]

Because of situations like this Nemo is not a default file manager in Ubuntu.

Comment: I know nemo is not the default for Ubuntu. But nemo is a fork of Nautilus

Comment: @JebediahKerman Is a fork which doesn't provide useful warnings :) In your title you are complaining about Ubuntu. But Ubuntu, in this case doesn't have any fault because you decided to change it's default programs. Nemo is default in Cinnamon.